# Нужно найти совпадение при генерации рандомных чисел

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно найти совпадение при генерации рандомных чисел
Создал код генерации рандомных чисел от 0 до 10, но нужно генерировать до того момента пока не сгенерируется например две 5, или две 3, или две 8 (без разницы), если сгенерировалось две 3 то показывать ошибку в виде alert('такая цифра уже есть (переменная с этой цифрой)')

```
<div class="button_random">btn</div>





$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( ".button_random" ).each(function(index) {
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            let number = Math.round(Math.random()*10);

            
            $( "<p class='test'>" + number + "</p>").appendTo( "body" );

            if (number == number) alert('errorrrrrrr');
        });
    });
```

});

Это я пробовал что-то чудить

Comment: так надо сохранять куда-то числа которые были. массив или объект.и соответственно проверять, было уже или нет. в чем сложность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".button_random").each(function(index) {
    let numbers = new Set();
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      let number = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
      if (!numbers.has(number)) {
        numbers.add(number);
        $("<p class='test'>" + number + "</p>").appendTo("body");
      } else {
        console.log('errorrrrrrr', number);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button_random">Click</button>
```